# Unable to click on the link

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, wait

I want to go to page1 then click on some other button for directing to page2 then click on a link that is on page2. 
My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as UI

d = webdriver.Firefox()
d.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
d.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="appbar-nav"]/ul/li[2]/a/span').click()
wait = UI.WebDriverWait(d, 20)
next_page_link = wait.until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'FACTS ABOUT ME')))
next_page_link.click()
```

I added wait, but it still giving the error:

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element is no longer attached to the DOM

Comment: I could not find any element with "FACTS ABOUT ME" as its link text,

Comment: I tried with `find_element_by_css_selector("a[title='FACTS ABOUT ME']")`, it worked for me. Can you please try using `find_by_css_selector` instead of `LINK_TEXT`?

Answer (score 0):

If an element is simply not in the DOM at all it will throw a NoSuchElementException. You are saying you received a StaleElementReferenceException. That exception occurs when the web driver searches for a matching element and finds one. You then have a reference to that element but before you click on it the element it is tied to is removed from the DOM. This is often because a JavaScript library has dynamically altered the DOM and removed the node from the page then put a new one in it's place. It appears (visually) to still be on the page but the element instance the driver had previously found isn't present any longer. The only real way to handle it, if you are on a site that uses JavaScript like this, is to wrap the location and execution in a loop and a try catch to retry again.

Comment: I mean do a loop (with some sort of timeout or n number of times in case of something going wrong) and do the lookup of the element (e.g. `driver.find_element_by_xpath`) and the clicking of the element inside of the loop (and also inside of a try catch block that ignores StaleElementReference exceptions